# Generating an alert message in katalon recorder

Tags: katalon-recorder

Is there any way I can generate custom popup message for browser. For example after successfully login I want to generate a custom browser popup message like “Login successfully”.

Answer (score 0):

An example with login to katalon site:

```
    import static com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.ObjectRepository.findTestObject

    import java.awt.Frame
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane

    import com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.WebUiBuiltInKeywords as WebUI

    WebUI.openBrowser('')
    WebUI.navigateToUrl("https://www.katalon.com/sign-in/")
    WebUI.waitForPageLoad(60)
    WebUI.click(findTestObject('user_email'))
    WebUI.setText(findTestObject('user_email'), "YOUR VALID USEREMAIL HERE")
    WebUI.click(findTestObject('user_pass'))
    WebUI.setText(findTestObject('user_pass'), "YOUR VALID PASSWORD HERE")
    WebUI.click(findTestObject('login-btn'))
    WebUI.waitForPageLoad(60)
    Boolean loginSuccessFul = WebUI.verifyElementPresent(findTestObject('signOutButton'), 10)
    if (loginSuccessFul) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new Frame('Login result'),
            "Login successful.")
    }
```

[image: result]

Maybe see more to java.awt and javax.swing at https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/index.htm

Comment: I am looking for katalon recorder command, not katalon studio script.